# How to place the array returned from a MySql count to a variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

PHP Code:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT COUNT(*) AS "total" FROM mydbfield');

echo $total;
echo total;

print "<pre>";
print_r($results);
print "</pre>"
```

Results array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [total] => 16876
    )
```

I want my answer to be like = 16876 not all the other stuff.

With this, my total for this table is `$total`. And it will print **16876**.

Do not want to see all that array stuff printed. I have spent a lot of time studying `php` in the W3.

Comment: start with adding your programming language. then reformulate your swearwords out and format your expected output in a nice way.

Comment: What is `echo $total` and `echo total` in your code?

Comment: with that i was just trying to show how i wanted it to work.
echo $total to get my answer.. which of course will not work.. but looks like i now have many solutions that will work.. thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

One way is with [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function. In your case, assuming `$results` always return an array with length equal to 1

```
$results = (array) reset($results); // or $results[0] instead of reset, then cast to array
extract($results);                  // Extract results
echo $total;                        // You can now use $total which returns 16876
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print $results[0]['total'];
```

get_results returns a set of rows. By definition you will only get one row on a `SELECT COUNT(*)`, so `$results[0]` gives you the one-and-only-one row and `$results[0]['total']` returns the desired value.

Comment: Thanks to all as several of the answers worked great but while i was waiting for an answer i came across this lightening fast solution.  My original was taking maybe 2 sec to count 20k records but this one does it in a flash..
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_realty_listingsdb", $link);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        echo "Total in Data Base -> $num_rows items<br>";

if someone will tell me how to mark a correct answer i will mark the first solution even though i wont be using it it gives me more tools for the future..

Comment: `SELECT *` followed by `mysql_num_rows()` is perfectly valid. However, if you are not going to make use of the actual rows returned then it is generally better to use `COUNT(*)` instead. The work inside the database is essentially the same but with `SELECT *` all the data has to be passed back to the PHP server, which is not necessarily the same physical server as the database server. With `COUNT(*)` only a single value needs to be sent back to PHP. Depending on cached queries and other factors, sometimes `SELECT *` will be super fast, but definitely not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above, you could try:

```
$total = $results[0]->total;
echo $total;
```

Or

```
$resultObj = current($results);
```

Which enables you to do:

```
$total = $resultObj->total;
echo $total;
```

I would suggest you read something like https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_arrays.asp, along with http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php to learn more about how results objects are returned in an array